# Angular ng-repeat view not updating after custom filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-router

I have an ng-repeat that filters out items based on a category chosen by the user. When the page renders the category is all and none of the items are filtered. There are three categories and the selected category is passed into the custom filter. When I debug I can see that the list is being properly updated when I change categories but the view isn't changing. If I click on one of the items in the list, ng-click is forcing a $digest and the view is rendered properly. Is there any way I can force the view to re-render after my custom filter? There's gotta be something else going on because I have custom filters working elsewhere.

I'm using ui-router so this view is the parent ui-view and below this I have another ui-view and in the parent controller I get the first story out of the list and load that subview. I'm not sure if that's what is affecting this or not.

View

```
<ul>
  <li ng-click="storyConfig.filter='all'">
    <div>All</div>
  </li>
  <li ng-click="storyConfig.filter='watch'">
    <div>Watch</div>
  </li>
  <li ng-click="storyConfig.filter='movement'">
    <div>Move</div>
  </li>
</ul>
<li ng-repeat="story in filteredStories = (allStories | stories:storyConfig.filter | orderBy:'datePosted':true)"
    ng-click="storyConfig.activeStoryId=story._id;$state.go('stories.story', {storyId:story._id})">
  <div>
    <div class="center">
      <h3>{{story.datePosted}}</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h4>{{story.headline}}</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
<li ng-if="filteredStories.length === 0 && storyConfig.filter === 'watch'">
  <div>
    <div class="center">
      <h6>You are not watching any stories</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Filter

```
app.filter('stories', ['StoryService', function(StoryService) {
  return function(stories, filter) {

    return stories.filter(function(story) {
      var add = false;
      if (filter === 'all' || (filter === 'movement' && story.movement === true)) {
        add = true;
      } else if (filter === 'watch') {
        angular.forEach(story.tags, function(tagId) {
          var tag = StoryService.getTag(tagId);
          if (tag !== undefined && tag.watch) {
            add = true;
          }
        });
      }

      return add;
    });
  };
}]);
```

Controller

```
app.controller('StoriesController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$state', 'StoryService',
  function($scope, $rootScope, $state, StoryService) {

  $scope.storyConfig = {};
  $scope.allStories = StoryService.getAll();
  $scope.storyConfig.filter = 'all';


  if ($scope.storyConfig.activeStoryId === undefined) {
    $scope.storyConfig.activeStoryId = $scope.allStories[0]._id;
  }
  $state.go('stories.story', {storyId:$scope.storyConfig.activeStoryId});
}]);
```

Comment: I have read this a couple times, and I still dont understand your problem.. Can you consider rewording? I partially dont understand the "simple toggle part".  It sounds like it works fine when you click.. so does that mean upon initial load its broke ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I reworded the first part a bit. The toggle is just the all, watch, and move from the HTML I posted. The page loads with All selected and when I click Watch the custom filter returns the list with only watched stories but the actual view is still showing all the stories.

Comment: I just took your code and created a small fiddle... but dont see the issue:    http://jsfiddle.net/ncapito/td6m3/  . I had to dumb it down and i also didn't use ui router.  I dont see anything bad in your code.

Comment: Everything works as expected when I first load my application but once I switch states with the ui router it starts to act up. That's why I brought up the ui-router in my description. It's really weird.

Comment: Do you reference any variables in your child state?  I recommend putting together a plunkr and it should be a pretty quick solve...

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested I figured out what the problem was. On each story list item I have a transition style applied. With this I am trying to swipe the story item to the left and have it animate off the screen and then remove it from the list after the animation completes.

```
ul li{
  position:relative;
  left:0;
  transition:left 0.2s ease;
}
ul li.swipe-left {
  left:-320px;
}
```

Any ideas why this might be throwing the timing of the angular $digest off? Is there a better way to animate a list item out of view with angular?